# ImportError: No module named 'bitex.api'; 'bitex' is not a package

Tags: python, python-module

I'm trying to work with a package but get the error

```
 ImportError: No module named 'bitex.api'; 'bitex' is not a package
```

This is the package:

```
https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/bitex
```

I tried reading more about packages on:

```
https://www.smallsurething.com/how-python-modules-and-packages-work/
```

But I cannot seem to understand why I'm getting the error, I thought that by added a dot you go into a folder and then it should import the class GeminiWSS.

I'm trying to run the example from the readme:

```
 from bitex.api.WSS import GeminiWSS
 import time

 wss = GeminiWSS()
 wss.start()
 time.sleep(5)
 wss.stop()

 while not wss.data_q.empty():
     print(wss.data_q.get())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you install the package?

Comment: is the name of your script `bitex.py`? Then you try to import your own script

Comment: @hansaplast Thank you that was the problem. I completely didn't think about this! Feeling pretty stupid right now.

Comment: @user3605780 you're not the first one to be bitten by that :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always have pip handle it for you and install module as global.

pip install git+https://github.com/nlsdfnbch/bitex

Just tried it inside a docker container and is installed as global, would advise you to install inside a virtual environment for instance

For anyone  viewing this answer, this relies on having pip and git installed on the machine

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the script was called bitex.py. Thanks Hansaplast